# Excel.BindingDataChangedEventArgs - get the changed location information

Tags: office-js

I am adding a Binding to a particular range, which is potentially very large.  However `Excel.BindingDataChangedEventArgs` does not include the changed location, unlike [`Excel.WorksheetChangedEventArgs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetchangedeventargs?view=office-js).

It would be nice to pass along the changed address when the Binding data changes.  Is there a way to get this data, with the current API?